# Using R with Leaflet and Shiny to produce WMS?

Tags: r, leaflet, wms, shiny

I've have been using R with Leaflet and Shiny to produce a web map that is accessible to the public online. It is a real-time air temperature map of Tasmania, Australia based on current Bureau or meteorology weather station observations. You can view a prototype here: http://144.6.226.103/shiny/

Is it possible to make this map available for use as a Web Map Service (WMS) using Shiny and Leaflet packages in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do in R you'd have to write a web server that handled the WMS protocol - there's all sorts of requests that the server would have to understand:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Service

It will probably be easier to use Geoserver or QGIS Server to create a WMS server that serves your data.

Another possibility may be to render it to tiles and serve it as a tile layer in your shiny app, but you'd first have to do the rendering - there's a QGIS plugin that can do this for a given raster at a set of zoom scales, but that wouldn't be a WMS service, it would be a tiled map service (TMS).

Comment: Thanks your reply. I ended up taking your advice and used GeoServer to serve the map outputs via WMS. I then used R to automate the delivery of the resulting GeoTIFFs via manipulation of the REST interface. I posted about this here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327267/use-r-to-publish-geotiff-as-wms-in-geoserver