# Use R to publish GeoTIFF as WMS in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, r, wms, geotiff-tiff

I’ve been trying to automate the publishing of GeoTIFF rasters as a Web Map Service (WMS) to GeoServer using R.
So far I’ve only been able to establish a new datastore from inside R using this:

```
system(paste('curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/xml" -d "<coverageStore><name>myraster</name><workspace>myworkspace</workspace><enabled>true</enabled><type>GeoTIFF</type><url> /usr/share/geoserver/data/data/myworkspace/myraster.tif</url></coverageStore>" "http:// my_mv_ip/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myworkspace/coveragestores"', sep=""))
```

Similarly, you can also do this using the geosapi package in R. (https://github.com/eblondel/geosapi/wiki).
But progressing to the next step of adding and publishing a GeoTIFF as a Web Map Service (WMS) has been problematic and raster management is currently not supported with geosapi.

How do I publish GeoTIFFs as WMS to GeoServer in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out by further configuring the REST interface.

1. Create the coverage store from the server-resident file (which automatically creates a coverage as well).

   ```
   system(paste('curl -f -k  -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d "/usr/share/geoserver/data/data/myworkspace/myraster.tif" "http:// my_mv_ip/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myworkspace/coveragestores/myraster/external.geotiff"',sep=""))
   ```
2. Set the SRS and enable the coverage:

   ```
   system(paste('curl -s -k  -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<coverage><srs>EPSG:3005</srs><enabled>true</enabled></coverage>" "http:// my_mv_ip/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myworkspace/coveragestores/myraster/coverages/myraster"',sep=""))
   ```

Reference: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/How-to-use-REST-to-create-a-coverage-from-a-TIF-file-with-no-explicit-SRS-td5330129.html